# ¿Porque no espera Promise All?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Tengo un problema a la hora de resolver varias promesas dentro de un map, con el cual "promisifico" cada una de las pasadas.

Aquí está el código:

```
await Promise.all( laminas.map(async lam => {
            try{
                if (lam.lado == null) await lamModel.qwe(c, lam)
                if (lam.lado != null) await lamModel.ewq(c, lam) 
                if (lam.tipo == 'AD' || lam.tipo == 'FP') {
                    await lamModel.generaNuevaLam(c, lam, infoLam.grupo); 
                    await lamModel.generaMovimientoLam(c, [lam]);
                    await lamModel.actualizaContador(c);
                    console.log("qwerty");
                }
            }catch(e){
                throw new Error(e.message);
            }
        }));
```

El problema es que cuando hago -> `generaNuevaLam()` y `generaMovimientoLam()` se realiza también una inserción que depende de que se actualice el contador con -> `actualizaContador()`. Si el contador se actualiza las inserciones anteriores se harán sin problema. El caso es que se ejecutan antes de que el contador se actualice. ¿No debería de esperar, y luego realizar la siguiente iteración del map?

Gracias de antemano.

EDITADO

Me he fijado que aunque yo entre llamada y llamada a los métodos del modelo pongo un console.log("adasdas") de cualquier cosa, y se ejecuta antes la llamada a `generaMovimientoLam(c, [lam])` que soltar los console.log(). Es como si la hiciera a la vez.

EDITADO 2

Investigando por ahí he encontrado que Promise.all() lo que hace es ejecutar las promesas en paralelo, no en serie. Quizá haya alguna alternativa, ¿Alguien conoce alguna? Por ahí he visto mapSeries de bluebird.

Comment: Hola Díaz! Todas las funciones en las que colocaste "await" están devolviendo una promise?

Comment: Correcto, todas devuelven promesas. El caso es que se ejecuta antes (supongamos que pasa dos veces por el condicional de 'tipo') la funcion generaMovimientoLam que el console.log("qwerty"). No lo acabo de entender, cuando se supone que tendría que ser: generaMovimiento(), generaNuevoLote(),  console.log(), y luego de nuevo ¿No?

Comment: Hola @H.Díaz, una pregunta, si resuelves todas las promesas que hay dentro del `map` y no devuelves nada, el Promise.all() no resuelve ninguna promise, verdad? Lo que necesitas es resolver todas las promises antes de llegar al método `actualizaContador()` por cada iteracion, correcto?

Comment: Exacto, lo que hacen las dos funciones antes es insertar ciertos registros en la base de datos. Pero que pasa, que la inserción depende de un número contador, el cual forma parte de la clave primaria, y es el valor que varía. Con lo cual yo cada vez que hago esas inserciones, necesito seguidamente aumentar ese contador para la siguiente inserción dentro del map. Ese contador también reside en una tabla de la base de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado la alternativa, y para mi en este caso, es la solución. Al grano:
`Promise.all()` realiza las promesas en paralelo, con lo cual las inserciones de las que dependía no se realizaban cuando lo necesitaba .... Pero encontré Bluebird. Ya había echado un vistazo a su documentación y lo he usado en algún caso, pero ... poco. La respuesta es su `.mapSeries()`. Lo que hace es realizar las promesas en serie, ejemplo de mi caso->

```
      await bluebird.mapSeries( laminas, async (lam, index) => {
            try{
                if (lam.lado == null) await lamModel.qwe(c, lam)
                if (lam.lado != null) await lamModel.ewq(c, lam) 
                if (lam.tipo == 'AD' || lam.tipo == 'FP') {
                    await lamModel.generaNuevaLam(c, lam, infoLam.grupo); 
                    await lamModel.generaMovimientoLam(c, [lam]);
                    await lamModel.actualizaContador(c);
                }
            }catch(e){
                throw new Error(e.message);
            }
        });
```

Con este cambio las promesas se ejecutan en orden, al menos en el que busco, y se soluciona mi problema. No obstante si alguien conoce otra alternativa o sabría como hacer un `.mapSeries()` "Casero" me gustaría que lo compartiera. Seguramente existan bastantes soluciones alternativas a esta.